# Can't override Tomcat default file size limit in UAT profile environment

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, tomcat, file-upload

For some reason I am not able to override Tomcat's settings about the file size limit when working with the UAT profile environment (everything works smoothly on SIT)

I am using Spring Boot 2.2 and i am adding these properties to the configuration file:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=25MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=25MB
```

However when i run my application on the Eclipse IDE (clean install and profile UAT) it gives me errors when I try to upload files which are greater than 1MB (which AFAIK is the default Tomcat's file limit size).

A couple more things to point out:

1. Both the *application-sit.properties* file and the *application-uat.properties* have all of the instructions placed in the same order.
2. When I try to upload file whose size is lower than 1MB i get another error which is UnsupportedMediaType and so I was wondering whether the problem was in my Angular front-end or in my Spring Boot back-end application.

Oh... and I run my SIT application locally while the UAT application is run in a VM (it wouldn't surprise me if it is something that has to do with the VM).

Thank you all in advance for the help, I'm open to answer if you need more informations.

Have a nice day.

**UPDATE**

As requested by *@PiotrP.Karwasz* I am including the Angular and Spring code I used to make the upload service:

`upload()` in `upload-service.service.ts`

```
  upload(file: File)  {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    return new Observable(((observer: Observer<any>) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.onreadystatechange = _ => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if(xhr.status === 200) {
            observer.next(xhr.response);
            observer.complete();
          }
          else {
            observer.error(xhr.response); 
          }
        } 
      };

      ///environment.baseUrl changes based on the active profile config
      let url = environment.baseUrl + constants.REST_UPLOAD_FILE; 
      xhr.open('POST', url, true);
      xhr.send(formData);
    }));
  }
```

`save()` in `FileStorageService.java`

```
@Override
public void save(MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        String filename = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getOriginalFilename()) 
                                        + " - " 
                                        +  new SimpleDateFormat("dd꞉MM꞉yyyy HH'h'꞉mm'min'꞉ss's'")
                                            .format(new Date())
                                            .toString()
                                            .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9.-⁄꞉]", "_") 
                                        + "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
        
        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), this.root.resolve(filename));
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Non posso salvare il file. Errore: " + e);
    }
}
```

Note that as far as I understood by making tests printing stuff on the Eclipse console it seems like it doesn't even get to the point of reaching the Spring Boot `save()` method and I've actually also tried printing things on the controller method (whose code will be linked below) that manages the incoming requests but it doesn't show anything either way so seems more like it's never reaching the controller too.

The controller method who takes care of the upload request is available at https://pastebin.com/EMZStXJw

Comment: How do you upload the file: is it through a HTML form? What `enctype` are you using? `multipart/form-data` or the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I am using Angular FormData to upload the file with a Drag and Drop area, you can check the HTML code here: https://pastebin.com/i83TV0CA

Here's the related component: https://pastebin.com/H0Xbhnpw

Also, if it can be helpful, my Angular code is based on this guide (I've just made a few changes to implement drag and drop and used XMLHttpRequest instead of the usual HttpClient to make the request since it gave me ambigous Cross Origin issues): https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-spring-boot-file-upload/

Comment: That covers the interface, but how is `uploadService.upload` implemented and the handler method on Spring's side? Can you add them to your question?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz first of all thank you for trying to help me out, I'm spending days at work just to solve this issue. I've updated my question as you requested. Since it does not print things on screen when I make a request to the controller method but it gives me specific exceptions related to the file size or the media type my best guess at this point is that when I deploy the .war application it misses something. I've also tried making the requests with Postman to the correct URL but same results.

Comment: The code you posted should work: check in your browser debug tools if the `Content-Type` of the XHR request is `multipart/form-data`. Are there any proxies between your browser and Tomcat that might change the `Content-Type`?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I am not sure about the proxies, is there a way to check it out...? 

BTW here you go, the Content-Type does NOT change on the HTTP Headers and this is the same one I get on my local environment so it should work, am I wrong?

`Content-Type` [here](https://ibb.co/tbrRXdb)
and `Response` [here](https://ibb.co/JjxDFfn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after extracting the `.war` file of my front-end build I finally got it and I'll put this here for anyone who may need it.

The thing is that my `environment.baseUrl` (see the `upload()` method in `upload-service.service.ts` file) was pointing to an *invalid* endpoint (I still have to figure out why the endpoint was behaving like that and why it was there in the first place) and so when I tried making the request i got ambigous errors that had nothing to do with the actual one.

Modifying the UAT configuration file was enough to make it work.

**TLDR;**

Make sure you are pointing to the right URL endpoint in your `UAT` configuration file and extract the `.war` to check your `application.properties` files.